# In my sentence can I add a comma to the word before?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, american-english

I want to know if adding a comma before the word "before" would be correct or not.

> I had been struggling to find partners for three years **before** I found the best partners who helped me to learn English.

Comment: I don't find Past Perfect Continuous ***had been struggling*** particularly idiomatic when coupled with ***before I found X*** in your example. If you're going to start with a continuous form, I think you should repeat it in the adverbial clause: *I had been **struggling** to find partners for three years before **finding** the best partners*. But actually I think I'd still prefer the continuous for the second clause regardless of whether you just use Simple Past in the first one: *I **struggled** to find partners for three years before I **finding** the best partners*. The comma is optional.

Comment: What is better of them? I had been struggling or I struggled.

Comment: I don't think "better" is really a relevant issue as regards the Simple or Perfect Continuous choice. It really is just a stylistic choice for native speakers, but as a general rule of thumb I'd advise *learners* to stick with simpler tense forms whenever there seems to be a choice. The business about the comma is also just  a stylistic choice (but ask yourself whether you'd ***pause*** in speech, since that's all the comma represents). But I'm not sure if there are valid grammatical / syntactic grounds for me not liking the specific combination of tenses + ***before*** in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think  it  is not  possible in the  sentence
 but  if  you begin with a subordinate  clause you  have to use a comma as in the given sentence.

> **Before I found the best partners who help me to  learn English, I had been struggling hard to find parterns**

If we begin the sentence with  a subordinate clause we have  to  use the comma before the main clause.

**If you work hard, you will pass**.

**You will pass if you work hard**.